# Make Square Fill Entire Window

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, projection-matrix

How do I determine what transforms I need to make a square fill an entire window in *modern* OpenGL. Say for example I have an 800 x 600 window and the coordinates with the vertices of two triangles extending from -1 and 1. Without any type of transformation, these coordinated would fill an 800 x 600 window because OpenGL's coordinates extend from -1 to 1. What if I want to use a standard MVP transformation, though? How do I determine what needs to be done in order to fill an entire window. Consider this code:

```
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(60.0f, 4.f/3.f, 0.1f, 100.0f); // gluPerspective equivalent for those who may not know about glm
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f));;
glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

with the same coordinates. I would now get a square somewhere in the middle of the window. Assuming I do not change the projection matrix, what changes would need to be made to the View and Model matrices? I understand the matrix math, but not how it relates to window coordinates themselves.

Could anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

For 2D elements (like a HUD) I generally set an ortographic matrix with left = 0, right = width, bottom = 0, top = height where width and height are the size of the window. znear = -1 and zfar = 1.

Then your rectangle vertices would be at 0, 0, width and height.

Is that what you want? I'm not sure why you want to use a perspective matrix for a rectangle that fills the screen.

Comment: I was never able to get ortho to work. Why doesn't this:  glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::ortho(0.f, 800.f, 0.f, 600.f, -1.f, 1.f);
    glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));;
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f) show a square with coordinates described above? Thanks!